# On a statement of Harry Browne

Tags: investing, investment-strategies, economics

I am reading a book on an investment strategy proposed by Harry Browne ([1999, *Fail-Safe Investing: Lifelong Financial Security in 30 minutes*, pp. 39–40](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fail_Safe_Investing/Lo25JhQOvwIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22a%20period%20during%20which%20living%20standards%20are%20rising,%20the%20economy%20is%20growing%22&pg=PA40)) known as the "permanent portfolio". He makes the following assumption/statement regarding an economy when he presents his reasoning:

> Your portfolio needs to respond well only to those broad movements. And they fit into four general categories:
>
> 1. Prosperity: A period during which living standards are rising, the economy is growing, business is thriving, interest rates usually are falling, and unemployment is declining.
> 2. Inflation: A period when consumer prices generally are rising. They might be rising moderately (an inflation rate of 6% or so), rapidly (10% to 20% or so, as in the late 1970s), or at a runaway rate (25% or more).
> 3. Tight money or recession: A period during which the growth of the supply of money in circulation slows down. This leaves people with less cash than they expected to have, which usually causes a recession — a period of poor economic conditions.
> 4. Deflation: The opposite of inflation. Consumer prices decline and the purchasing power of money grows. In the past, deflation has usually triggered a depression — a prolonged period of very bad economic conditions, as in the 1930s.
>
> Investment prices can be affected by what happens outside the financial system — wars, changes in government policies, new tax rules, civil turmoil, and other matters. But these events have a lasting effect on investments only if they push the economy from one to another of the four environments I've just described.

To what extent is this assumptions "true" or vaild? Are these all the relevant and/or existing states of an economy and are the suggested asset types(stocks,long/short bond and gold) really balancing this in a nice way,theoretically?

Does it have any apparent theoretical drawbacks restriction attention to these four?

I also posted this on the [Economics Stack](https://economics.stackexchange.com/) but without luck. I am aware that everyone has to evaluate info using their own logic, hence don't worry about that!

Comment: My two cents is that while true, broad stroke macro statements like these are great for academia but not that realistic for everyday investing.  It's just not practical to believe that one is going to be able to identify these trends in a timely fashion and adjust one's holdings to continuously benefit from that analysis.

Comment: @BobBaerker the idea is to diversify given these states/phenomena and then fix the weights over the chosen intruments permanently and only do yearly rebalacing. Also I am just tying to verify that the theoretical basics in marco really supports the reasoning he is presenting. Naturally theory will only be theory, but it is still good to have a basis.

Comment: @BobBaerker hence there are no other rather basic and similar concepts that one would learn in a say masters course in macro? that trivially/obviously will have significant impact on a savings startegy that includes the basic instruments(stocks,bond and gold)

Comment: You want  to diversify these states/phenomena and  fix the weights over the chosen instruments permanently and only do yearly rebalancing. There's a big missing piece of this puzzle. Assuming that you deem these  states/phenomena valid, how do you quantify them  and then what instruments will fulfill those criteria?  And what makes you think that rebalancing them once a year  will catch the macro changes in a timely fashion?

Comment: The process should be to determine the macro picture, be able identify when they shift, identify the instruments that react to each phenomena and then back test the entire historical database to find out what periodicity works best (adjust monthly? Semi-annually? Yearly?) then implement and hope that the future periodicity matches historical occurrence.  That sounds like a career choice rather than an investing strategy.  I'm not knocking it, just saying that IMO it would be no mean feat to accomplish this, probably more suited to economists and quants at Goldman Sachs et al.

Comment: @Bob: re "chosen instruments"... Harry Browne's guidance on assets for each "climate" was 1: Equities, 2: Precious Metals, 3: Short dated bonds or cash, 4: Long dated bonds.  There's a nice analysis of how a 4x25% portfolio has performed here: https://portfoliocharts.com/portfolio/permanent-portfolio/

Comment: @timday - Thanks for the link.  Assuming my read is correct, the stats suggest a CAGR of less than 5% for the portfolio.  That's worse than the market's CAGR for the past 20 years which was the worst 20 year period since 1928. I'm not trying to be argumentative.  The macro picture isn't my strong suit.  Just curious.   What's the edge?

Comment: @Bob Baerker the idea is that one puts 25 % in stocks, long bond, short bond and gold/silver. And since boom/recessions and inflation/deflation are counterparts no quatification is needed. But thats what I am questioning. The above intruments should ofset eachother in the respective enviorment.

Comment: @Bob: HBPP enthusiasts don't tend to care so much about maximising CAGR as minimising other unpleasantnesses like variability of returns, maximum drawdown, recovery time, Safe WR etc (if you play around with it, PortfolioCharts can rank all the portfolios it has on these metrics).  But IHMO it's more a portfolio for staying rich, not so much for getting rich.

Comment: Another approach that formalizes the idea of a portfolio being robust to different economic environments is Risk Parity, specifically Bridgewater’s All Weather Portfolio formulation.

Comment: @BobBaerker I did some thinking on this,  by "Prosperity" and "Tight money"  I assume he means the basic "Busniess cycle trends" aka boom and recession(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_cycle). Inflation and deflation is in some sense well defined concepts which we know what he means atleast. Thus his model/idea rests upon the idea that we need to have intruments reacting to the movement of GDP in some sense(or the busniess cycles) and moreover the dynamics of "value of money" and dept which are contained within inflation/deflation mirroiring.

Comment: @BobBaerker do you agree with this interpretation of what he has written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re "Are these all the relevant and/or existing states of an economy?":

According to this interesting 2015 seekingalpha article "[The Permanent Portfolio Is Dead](https://seekingalpha.com/article/3325355-the-permanent-portfolio-is-dead)", the PP would not be expected to do well in conditions of "[secular stagnation](http://lexicon.ft.com/Term?term=secular-stagnation)".  Since secular stagnation is pretty much defined by an absence of any of the 4 economic conditions in the Harry Browne list, this isn't really surprising.

Re "are the suggested asset types(stocks,long/short bond and gold) really balancing this in a nice way?":

That seekingalpha piece also has some analysis of why the PP has worked in the past (hint: gold), and the performance analysis at [PortfolioCharts](https://portfoliocharts.com/portfolio/permanent-portfolio/) also demonstrates that it does have some nice properties (or at least it has in the past) compared with other approaches (however also note that the "Golden Butterfly" variant is arguably even better).

Comment: "Economic contraction and expansion relate to the overall output of all goods and services, while the terms inflation and deflation refer to increasing and decreasing prices of commodities, goods and services in relation to the value of money." is written on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_expansion. Which I assume is what Harry Browne is refering to aswell above. It seams that these are considered the main movements of an economy, can you think of other phenomena besides these four? secular stagnation looks like somthing that is defined in terms of these.I.e are there any addiational..

Comment: ..not depending on the four by definition?